# Quesstion about outer measure definition

Tags: measure-theory

Reading "A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory", and in the definition of outer measure of a set A, we take the infimum over the measure of covering sets for A from the semi-algebra (e.g., intervals in [0,1] ).

Is this set over which we are taking the infimum well-defined? For a given real
number x, how can I tell if x is in this set? I have to find a class of sets A1, A2, ... from the semi-algebra such that x = P(A1)+P(A2)+...

It is not clear how to find at least one such class (and hence determine if x is in this set), or determine that I *cannot* find such a class and hence x is *not* in the set. Any clarification is appreciated.

Comment: If you are talking about an outer measure on $\mathbb R$: You have $\mathbb R = \bigcup_{n=-\infty}^\infty (n, n+1]$. Thus, the infimum is always over a non-empty set of extended numbers. One of these numbers might be $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your question is.  Given a specific set, $A$, no, there do not necessarily exist **measurable** sets that contain $A$.  In that case, $A$ itself is NOT measurable.  I suspect that, in what you are doing, it is assumed that $A$ is measurable so that there exist measurable sets containing $A$.

Comment: I think there *does* necessarily exist a measurable set that contains $A$ for any $A$.  Just take the universal set.

Comment: Please start using LaTeX, see this guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Almost all of your posts need heavy editing

Answer (score 0):

You construct semi-rings $A_n \subseteq [0,1]$ in such a way that $A \subseteq \cup^{\infty}_{n=1} A_n$. The outer measure can now be found by finding:
$$\mu^{*}(A)= \inf\left\{\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \mu(A_n)\right\}$$.
If there is a measurable cover for $A$, the outer measure is well defined.