# Confusion on the construction of "Outer Measures"

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, outer-measure

**Background:** I am currently I am reading Angus and Taylor's, "General Theory of Functions and Integration". I'm reading it because they do a pretty nice job of explaining things but I have also read other books that discuss the Lebesgue integral and define outer measure in the same manner. I've always been confused by the definition. Angus and Taylor define the outer measure as:

> $u^{*}(E) = glb\left(\sum_{n} |I_{n}| : \space\{I_{n}\} \text{ is a  
>  Lebesgue covering of E} \right )$.

What I don't understand is, given that one might be able to construct some gigantic covering, how can there be any bound on $u^{*}(E)$ ?

Maybe if someone could provide an example where the infimum is actually used, that might open my eyes. For example, after they define outer measure, they say that:

> *"a single open interval I is a Lebesgue covering of itself. Therefore, $u^{*}(I) \le |I|$".*

I don't see why that is the case because I don't see how the infimum comes into play ?

Thanks a lot (in advance) for any example or statement that could help me to understand the definition. I have read the [following thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1360835/quesstion-about-outer-measure-definition) - which may be of some relevance here, but this does not answer the particular issues I've raised above (at least not directly).

Comment: It sounds like you are confused by the definition of "infimum". Infimum tells you how *small* something can be. Thus, it is completely irrelevant how *big* it can be. For the outer measure, we are trying to cover the set $E$ with as tiny as possible (in terms of total size) collection of intervals.

Comment: Regarding what @Stinking Bishop said, it might help to pretend we using "minimum" instead of "infimum" (keeping in the back of our mind that maybe the minimum doesn't exist, so we'd have to use the unattained end point where the minimum would have been). Suppose $M = \{a, \, b, \, c, \, \ldots \},$ where $M$ could contain a finite,  or countably infinite, or uncountably infinite number of elements (i.e. the ellipsis here doesn't specifically mean countably infinite). Since $a\in M$ and $b \in M$ and $\ldots,$ it follows that $\min M \leq a$ and $\min M \leq b$ and $\ldots$ **(continued)**

Comment: In your case, $|I|$ is one of the elements of the set $M$ (because $|I|$ arises by using a certain covering), so the minimum of the elements in your set (the set of values you get for various coverings) is less than or equal to $|I|.$ Interestingly, while it initially might seem obvious, when $I$ is a bounded open interval, that surely you can't get something less than $|I|$ for coverings (how can you do better than to just let the covering be $I$ itself?), proving this "obviously intuitive result" is a bit tricky.

Comment: Indeed, even [proving the infimum is greater than zero is not all that immediate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3087767/13130).

Comment: I will read all of these carefully. Thanks.

Comment: I get it now. I was thinking of the infimum in the wrong way. All of your answers and clarity is appreciated. Thanks.